# SQL Query or PHP Query from Excel Sheets

Tags: php, sql, cs-cart

My suppliers in South Africa do not use live xmls for their stock lists.

Each of our suppliers stock lists ( excel pricelists ) have very different layouts. The only way I currently do updates is by copying the code and the price into a new excel csv sheet and import. Then the product codes that it can’t pickup will automatically be put in the “products” category with just the code and the price. The rest I do manually. Adding the short description, product name and correct category.

Is there anyway to make this more automated. We currently have over 15 different pricelists and in excess of 30k products.

I want it to automatically fetch the products image from google based on the products name. Automatically add it to the correct category? I assume I would have to set conditions such as code starting with MO- go to computers///peripherals///mouses. Or for it to ask me to set conditions to look for in product code or short descriptions then it will do the rest?

I also want that when a product is missing from the pricelists it gets hidden.

Is this possible?

Comment: What about using a standard approach: a small script working on a small database?

Comment: Well I am willing to pay for something made.

Comment: No the product image is not attached to the excel sheet

Answer (score 0):

Well, PHP has all the tools you need:

1. [Database Interface](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.database.php)
2. [Getting the contents of a web page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) (Hopefully you could get the image by some method other than Google search, because that would be unreliable: how would you know you got the right result? But there are lots of examples of people using PHP to search Google--just search the internet).
3. [Writing an Excel file](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/).

Or in Perl, my preferred tool: [`DBI`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm), [`LWP::Simple`](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.04/lib/LWP/Simple.pm), and [`Spreadsheet::WriteExcel`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm).

I would not try doing this with VBA in Excel if you have other options.  In my experience, that leads to repeatedly hitting one's head against the wall.  It probably is possible to do it that way, as well, though.

Comment: Would any developer be willing to help me create something like this at cost, as I am not coder.

Comment: @WarrenPleass, I'm sure someone would, but this is not the right forum for that.  Hopefully someone can direct you to the right place, because I don't know what the best site is.